# How to correctly return pointer to array of chars?

Tags: c++, algorithm, io

I have the following code to read from file, it uses byte-at-a-time system call I/O and is thus quite slow

```
int readc(io61_file* f) {
    unsigned char buf[1];
    ssize_t nr = read(f->fd, buf, 1);
    if (nr == 1) {
        return buf[0];
    } else if (nr == 0) {
        errno = 0; // clear `errno` to indicate EOF
        return -1;
    } else {
        assert(nr == -1 && errno > 0);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

This is how I use it

```
// io_read(f, buf, sz)
//    Reads up to `sz` bytes from `f` into `buf`. Returns the number of
//    bytes read on success. Returns 0 if end-of-file is encountered before
//    any bytes are read, and -1 if an error is encountered before any
//    bytes are read.
//
//    Note that the return value might be positive, but less than `sz`,
//    if end-of-file or error is encountered before all `sz` bytes are read.
//    This is called a “short read.”
ssize_t io_read(io61_file* f, unsigned char* buf, size_t sz) {
    size_t nread = 0;
    while (nread != sz) {
        int ch = readc(f);
        if (ch == EOF) {
            break;
        }
        buf[nread] = ch;
        ++nread;
    }
    if (nread != 0 || sz == 0 || errno == 0) {
        return nread;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I want to speed up this code and as the first step, I want to increase the `buf` size inside `readc` to 10. How to do this correctly? As the first step I decided to return an array of size 1 from `readc` but it doesn't work as expected. Where I made a mistake?

```
unsigned char* io_readc2(io61_file* f) {
    static unsigned char buf[1];
    ssize_t nr = read(f->fd, buf, 1);
    if (nr > 0 && nr < 2) {
        return buf;
    } else if (nr == 0) {
        errno = 0; // clear `errno` to indicate EOF
        static unsigned char t[1];
        t[0] = -1;
        return t;
    } else {
        assert(nr == -1 && errno > 0);
        static unsigned char t[1];
        t[0] = -1;
        return t;
    }
}
```

```
ssize_t io_read(io61_file* f, unsigned char* buf, size_t sz) {
    size_t nread = 0;
    while (nread != sz) {
        unsigned char* chars = io_readc2(f);
        int ch = *chars;
        if (ch == EOF) {
            break;
        }
        buf[nread] = ch;
        ++nread;
    }
    if (nread != 0 || sz == 0 || errno == 0) {
        return nread;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect you are writing "C" (since a see a lot of use of "naked" pointers). But in C++ just return a std::string (or std::vector<char>). Either way "C" and "C++" are different languages so pick only one tag. And you can also remove the "algorithm" tag there is no real algorithm here.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work as expected" mean?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have a bunch of tests that test my code correctness and they fail, which means that I made not equivalent transformation

Comment: In your particular case, instead of trying to get `readc()` to create an array of `char` and return that, try changing `readc()` to accept a `char *` and have `io_read()` pass `buf` using that argument.

Comment: `static unsigned char buf[1];`?  Why `static`?  All that does is make your code multithread-**unsafe** and non-reentrant.

Comment: Do you want a C answer, or a C++ answer?  You really do have to pick one or the other.

Comment: The logical bug in the revised code should be very obvious when using your debugger to step through the code, one line at a time, and see what's happening. This is a golden opportunity for you to learn how to use your debugger, something that every C++ developer must learn how to use, and see exactly why the logic fails, in a very, very obvious manner.

Comment: @JohnZwinck c++

Comment: @AndrewHenle do you recommend returning the address of the local var?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik wasn't able to find it

Comment: What does "wasn't able to find it" mean? When you ran your code in a debugger, what exactly did you see happening when one of the tests failed?

Comment: @PepijnKramer: arrays of chars are also C++.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes they are, but they also cause a lot of bugs when passed as pointers (pointer decay) and when the need to be returned from functions ownership is dubious at best.  Thus  they are not my first choice to teach beginning C++ programmers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for an intermediate buffer.  Just take the data from the standard library and write it into the output buffer:

```
// f->fd is the file descriptor to read from
// buf is the output, sz is the maximum bytes to read
// return value is the number of bytes read
// if there was an error, returns -1 with error != 0
// if there was no data available, returns -1 with errno == 0
ssize_t io_read(io61_file* f, unsigned char* buf, size_t sz)
{
    ssize_t nr = read(f->fd, buf, sz);
    if (nr == 0 && sz != 0)
    {
        errno = 0;
        return -1;
    }
    return nr;
}
```

Edit: since you say you need an intermediate buffer, here you go:

```
// same effect as io_read() but with extra buffering for some reason
ssize_t io_read_extra(io61_file* f, unsigned char* buf, size_t sz)
{
    std::vector<char> innerbuf(sz);
    ssize_t nr = read(f->fd, innerbuf.data(), sz);
    if (nr == 0 && sz != 0)
    {
        errno = 0;
        return -1;
    }
    if (nr > 0)
    {
        memcpy(buf, innerbuf.data(), nr);
    }
    return nr;
}
```

Comment: could please also provide a code with an intermediate buffer, I need it

Comment: @indigo153 You do realize any of your calls to your `io_read( f, buf, sz )` could all be directly replaced with `read( f->fd, buf, sz )` and all that extraneous code doing byte-by-byte reads removed?

Comment: @AndrewHenle yes

Comment: @indigo153: OK, I added `io_read_extra()` which does intermediate buffering.

Comment: I've updated the specification of my function, not sure that your version is equivalent to mine

Comment: Does it handle short reads?

Comment: Yes, it handles short reads.  But don't take my word for it, write some unit tests!

Comment: I checked, and it doesn't.

Comment: @indigo153: You're not being clear.  Your original code did not read beyond a "short read."  Are you saying you want code which responds to a "short read" by calling `read()` again until the buffer is full or EOF is encountered?  If so, why does the original code in your question say *"Note that the return value might be positive, but less than `sz`"*?